# Hide suggestion list from HERE Maps in SearchBox after onSelect

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm using the **nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox** control to search for places and center/zoom on the map the item picked by the user.

For that purpose I'm using the *onSelect* event, because it should respond to user selection (opposite to the *onResults* event that fired after the results are returned). 
After centering the map I'm calling the hideSuggestions() method to hide the result list of the SearchBox.

My problem is that when the item is selected the suggestion list disappear correctly but remains "interactive". In particular, scrolling with the mouse wheel, the search box rolls over the search items.

Is there a native way to definitely close the suggestion list apart from removing manually items from the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming convention for the callbacks in the [SearchBox documentation](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox.html#topic-apiref__SearchBox-0)  is at best ambiguous. The `onResults()` callback is only fired once the user has **accepted** a result, and only if the custom handler `onSelect()` has not been defined.

From your description it looks like you are after the standard behavior of the **SearchBox**, so I would suggest you try something like this:

```
var fromSearchBox = new nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox({
        targetNode: "fromSearchBox",
        template: "fromSearchBox",
        map: map,
        onResults: function (data) {
            startPoint =data.results.items[0].position;
            alert("fires");
            map.set("center", data.results.items[0].position);
        }
    });
```

When I run this I get an `alert()` when the user chooses a selection, the results are hidden, the map is centered on the result and the mouse scroll wheel has no further effect.

Comment: I fully agree with you, the naming convention is very unclear. Anyway, your suggestion worked well.

Comment: With `data.results.items[0]` I'm always picking the first item from the list. How could I find the real selected item?

Comment: Actually with `data.results.items[0]` you are selecting the best match to the _suggestion in the suggestion box_. For example, if you type "FRA" and select "_Frankfurt Airport_" `data.results.items[0]` **is** the best match to the suggestion -  `data.results.items[1]` would give _Frankfurt Hahn_ 90km away which is where Ryanair fly to. Something like [this example](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/examples.html#directions-rendering-component__suggestion-box-with-directions) on the HERE Maps community pages works for me.

Comment: The example does not work in my case. 
When I try to search for a city which is present in more than a country but with identical name, I cannot select results different from the first in the result list.
In your example, try to search for _"Bayswater"_ in the from textbox.

Comment: Worldwide Geolocation of cities, districts, addresses etc. is the domain of the [Geocoding API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder). Places is focused on **local** search - finding and suggesting a restaurant nearby and so on. It always answers the question _Where can I find an X_ **near to** _Y?_ If I focus the map on Scotland and ask for _Perth to Wycombe_ it will retrieve a different pair of locations than if I focus on Australia. I think your use-case (_"Find Perth, Scotland when looking at Australia"_) doesn't fall within the standard use of the places widget.

Comment: So I need to implement my own autocomplete control using the Geocoding API and avoid the SearchBox widget. Thanks again for your help.